# Storage folder not getting commited into github in laravel project

Tags: laravel, git, github, laravel-artisan

In my laravel project after recently doing `php artisan storage:link` i comitted my project in github then i noticed the storage folder in my public folder is not comitted. How can i fix this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your `.gitignore` file. I guess the storage folder is excluded. Remove it from your .gitignore file and add, commit and push again and everything should get pushed to github.

@edit
remove the `public/storage` from your .gitignore file.
But keep in mind, like mentioned in the comments, that you might want to keep some files locally.

Comment: This is likely the case, but bear in mind that you may not want to commit all the content of the storage folder into your repository. Be selective and only commit files which would be considered "static" and unlikely to be changed

Comment: @Aless55 .gitgnore file in my root directory or my storage directory?

Comment: @Spholt yeah that is the reason why there is a link between storage in root directory and the storage in public directory.

Comment: @WigglyFaun Spholt is right about the consistency and security aspect, but somewhere in your main .gitignore file should be a line like `public/storage` which should be removed if you want the public/storage folder in your repo

Comment: @Aless55 do i need to remove that `public/storage` in the image i attached above.

Comment: @WigglyFaun yes exactly

Answer (score 1):

move to `$> cd storage/app/public` then `git add * -f` then you can push, hope it helps somehow.

Answer (score 0):

My project created via new laravel project had `.gitignore`s all over the place to stop files from being committed via `/storage/app/public`, so I had to remove those to preload my project with some files in that folder.

Look around for those gitignores in your project tree. There's one in the root directory, but there's also some in `/storage` and I think even `/storage/public`.

That's 2 or 3 dangerous settings.